# Какой предлог использовать? "В" или "На"?

Tags: предлоги

Интересный случай. Какой применить предлог при употреблении на письме словосочетания: Каждое Ваше появление **в (на?) Sweet Casino** – праздник для нас!

Когда мы идем играть в казино закрытое, понятно, что употребляем с предлогом "в", а если речь об онлайн-казино?

Answer (score 1):

**Каждое Ваше появление в Sweet Casino – праздник для нас!**

Здесь два варианта, например:

1) Заходите **в круглосуточное  онлайн-казино** (название казино), и тогда вы сможете окунуться в мир драйва, азарта и экстрима. (Часто пишут без дефиса, но это не по правилам).

2) Хотите поиграть в этот игровой автомат, но не знаете, где лучше сделать это? Тогда **заходите на сайт** (название казино).

Таким образом, сочетание ***в онлайн-казино*** приближает сетевое казино к реальному. Но если речь идет о сайте компании или имеется в виду сайт компании, то используется традиционный предлог НА.  Поэтому вариант "Каждое Ваше появление на Sweet Casino – праздник для нас!" **не является ошибочным.**

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта имеют право на существование.

"Ваше появление в Sweet Casino" – внимание читателя направлено на то, что это казино (что следует из названия), пусть даже виртуальное.

"Ваше появление на Sweet Casino" – внимание читателя направлено на то, что это сайт, пусть даже в его названии есть слово Casino.

Comment: Варианты имеют право на существование, но какой вы сделаете выбор  для этого конкретного случая?  Куда направите внимание читателя?

Comment: @Jasmin, Не берусь ответить, не видя контекста.

Comment: Считайте, что контекста нет, просто надо составить одно  рекламное предложение.

Comment: @Jasmin, На мой взгляд, рекламировать надо услугу (казино), а не площадку, на которой оно расположено (будь то здание для реального казино или сайт для виртуального): «Ваше появление в Sweet Casino».

Comment: Если Вам нужен конкретный игровой автомат, то они приглашают зайти на сайт, где представлены все игры.

Comment: @Jasmin Вы знаете что-то, чего я не знаю, некий контекст. Что я могу утверждать в таких условиях? Если приглашают зайти на сайт, тогда НА.

Comment: Да какие там знания, это просто минимальная информация из Интернета об устройстве этих виртуальных казино.  Без нее было бы сложно отвечать на вопрос.